# SQLite CASE, IF RESULT FROM SUB QUERY

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, case

I have the following SQL query in a SQLite 3 database

```
  UPDATE Events 
  SET location = CASE 
        WHEN identifier = (SELECT id FROM users_db.exerciseLists WHERE patientId = ? AND complete = 1) 
        THEN 'yellow' 
        WHEN identifier = ? 
        THEN 'green' 
        WHEN date_start < datetime('now') 
        THEN 'red' 
        WHEN date_start > datetime('now') 
        THEN 'blue' 
        ELSE 'green' 
        END, 
  type = CASE 
        WHEN identifier = ? 
        THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE 'no' 
        END
```

The sub query

```
  (SELECT id FROM users_db.exerciseLists WHERE patientId = ? AND complete = 1)
```

Returns more than one result, however the above case query is only using the first returned result.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sub query returns more than one result and you want to update for all returned results then it would be better to use IN statement like this:

```
WHEN identifier IN (SELECT id FROM users_db.exerciseLists WHERE patientId = ? AND complete = 1)
```

Comment: It could be even better to include the id=identifier in the subquery's where clause